# Android - How to cache Json using SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite, caching

My application should work not only in online but also in offline mode. When my app have internet connection, it will download data (parse from Json) and save to SQLite database. If I turn off internet, it will get data from SQLite to display. My problems are how I know when data update or have new data from server. I want update current records and add new records when data change.

Ex:

First load - Load 50 records >>> save to SQLite

Second load - Load 30 records (20 current records change & 15 new records)

Total - 65 records in SQLite

Thanks for any help

Comment: set primary or composite key on table and insert data with replace with conflicts it will replace the old data with latest

Comment: I just want get new or modify data . Not replace old data by new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like more of a server API issue than anything. Your app needs to know when it went offline (we'll call this `lastCommTime`). When the application is back online you need to query the server for 1) records that have been updated since `lastCommTime` and 2) records that were inserted since `lastCommTime`.

How you handle this on the backend is a design decision you'll have to make. Many web application frameworks have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Comment: I have resolved new records by set created field in my database. But don't know what record has modify. I was think using updated. It doesn't work because there are many records and time updated not synchronize

Comment: Andy's solution sounds reasonable,
just query your table with lastCommTime which you know when you updated your table after downloading is done and you will get updated and new rows.
Now If you want to segregate updated and newly added rows then you have created_at and updated_at fields to check.